# CrossEntropyLoss on sequences

Tags: pytorch

I need to compute the `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss` on sequences.

- The output tensor `y_est` has shape: `[batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_dim]`. The values are embedded as one-hot vectors with `embedding_dim` dimensions (`y_est` is not binary however).
- The target tensor `y` has shape: `[batch_size, sequence_length]` and contains the integer index of the correct class in the range `[0, embedding_dim)`.

If I compute the loss on the two input data, with the shape described above, I get an error [1](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html).

What I would like to do is described by the cycle at [2]. For each sequence in the batch, I would like the sum of the losses computed on each element in the sequence.

After reading the documentation of [torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) I came up with the solution [3], which seems to compute exactly what I want: the losses computed at point [2] and [3] are equale.

However, since `.permute(.)` returns a view of the original tensor, I am afraid it might mess up the backward propagation on the loss. Somewhere (I do not remember where, sorry) I have read that views should not be used in computing the loss.

Is my solution correct?

```
import torch

batch_size = 5
seq_len = 10
emb_dim = 100

y_est = torch.randn( (batch_size, seq_len, emb_dim))
y = torch.randint(0, emb_dim, (batch_size, seq_len) )

print("y_est, batch x seq x emb:", y_est.shape)
print("y, batch x seq", y.shape)

loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction="none")

# [1]
# loss = loss_fn(y_est, y)
# error:
# RuntimeError: Expected target size [5, 100], got [5, 10]

[2]
loss = 0
for i in range(y_est.shape[1]):
    loss += loss_fn ( y_est[:, i, :], y[:, i]).sum()
print(loss)    

[3]
y_est_2 = torch.permute( y_est, (0, 2, 1))
print("y_est_2", y_est_2.shape)
loss2 = loss_fn(y_est_2, y).sum()
print(loss2)
```

whose output is:

```
y_est, batch x seq x emb: torch.Size([5, 10, 100])
y, batch x seq torch.Size([5, 10])
tensor(253.9994)
y_est_2 torch.Size([5, 100, 10])
tensor(253.9994)
```

Is the solution correct (also for what concerns the backward pass)? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If `y_est` are probabilities you really want to compute the error/loss of a categorical output in each timestep/element of a sequence then `y` and `y_est` have to have the same shape. To do so, the categories/classes of `y` can be expanded to the same dim as `y_est` with one-hot encoding

```
import torch
batch_size = 5
seq_len = 10
emb_dim = 100

y_est = torch.randn( (batch_size, seq_len, emb_dim))

y = torch.randint(0, emb_dim, (batch_size, seq_len) )
y = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(y, num_classes=emb_dim).type(torch.float)

loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = loss_fn(y_est, y)
print(loss)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon the same question, and seeing nobody had an answer here I took upon myself testing it.

#### **TL;DR**

To my surprise, the two methods proposed by OP are **not equivalent**, *ie* result in vastly different networks after training. The best method seems to be the number 2 as proposed by OP: compute the CrossEntropyLoss function on each element of the sequence independently, and sum. It consistently gives a network that learnt the task better than with the other methods, for the specific task I used at least.

---

#### Code repository

I've created a git repository for those that would be interested in seeing the complete code and results, and in playing with them (and report any mistake I may have made ^^'). It's on github: https://github.com/mascartcyrille/SeqCrossEntropyLoss

#### Quick test

Reproducing OP's test, I find exactly the same surface result: up to *10e-4*precision, the two methods give the same loss. Furthermore, when evaluating `loss==loss2`, I find `tensor(True)`. However, changing batch_size to 32, the result changes to

```
loss        | tensor(1620.4897)
loss2       | tensor(1620.4896)
loss==loss2 | tensor(False)
```

The probable issue is that rounding errors may accumulate with time and batch sizes. The effect of the loss computation method on gradient computation is also unclear to me. I'm no expert in Pytorch inner workings, but I wanted to at least have an experimental conclusion, so here it is.

#### Full Answer

So here's the project: test different ways of computing the `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss` function, and determine what's the best way to compute the loss function of a RNN outputting entropic sequences of variable lengths.

To achieve that I imagined the following task: give to a RNN sequences of images of numbers from the MNIST data set. Sequence length is between 1 and 11. The RNN has to: recognize the number in each image (one-hot encoded), then output the sum as a sequence of [decimal, unit]. For instance, given 5 vectors of size (28*28=784), 3 representing the handwritten numbers 3, 5 and 7, and the last two filled with zeros, the RNN should output, 5 one-hot encoded numbers, respectively 3, 5, 7, 1, 5 (3+5+7=15, hence the last two numbers in the sequence). I will then train one separate network for each ways to compute the loss. The RNG seed will be reset each time, so that the randomness should be exactly the same in each situation. This way, if the computations are equivalent, the *networks should have more or less the same weights* at the end of training (I predict some rounding errors because of some differences in sum operation ordering).

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.inpt = nn.Linear(28*28, 100)
        self.rtnn = nn.GRU(100, 10, batch_first=True)
        self.oupt = nn.Linear(10, 10)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        oupt, hddn = self.rtnn(self.inpt(x))
        return self.oupt(oupt), hddn
```

I'll test the following ways to compute the loss.

1. Compute the loss of each element of the sequence independently, then sum (OP's method 2)
2. Use `torch.permute` to swap the sequence dimension `L` with the class dimension `C` (OP's method 3)
3. Use `torch.swapdims` to swap the sequence dimension `L` with the class dimension `C` (should be equivalent to permute)
4. Use `torch.swapaxes` to swap the sequence dimension `L` with the class dimension `C` (should be equivalent to permute)
5. Use `torch.swapdims`, but this time with `reduction=sum` in the parameters of `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`
6. Use `torch.swapdims`, but this time with `reduction=mean` in the parameters of `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`
7. Compute the loss of each element of the sequence independently, but this time with `reduction=sum` in the parameters of `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`

```py
loss_fnct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction="none")
loss_fnct5 = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction="sum")
loss_fnct6 = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction="mean")
```

###### Results

###### Loss values

The loss for methods 2, 3 and 4 are exactly the same: same exact loss at each time step, same exact parameters for each component of the network.

```
            loss 2 / 3 / 4
Epoch 001 | loss 340.57012939453125 / 340.57012939453125 / 340.57012939453125
[...]
Epoch 100 | loss 298.14556884765625 / 298.14556884765625 / 298.14556884765625
```

The loss for methods 1 is different from all the other ones, and ends up lower than the other losses.

```
Epoch 001 | loss 338.1639404296875
[...]
Epoch 100 | loss 49.7880744934082
```

The loss for methods 5 is very similar to the losses of methods 2, 3, and 4, but slightly different, probably due to accumulating rounding errors.

```
Epoch 001 | loss 340.5700988769531
[...]
Epoch 100 | loss 298.1455993652344
```

Methods 6 and 7's losses are incomparable to the others.

```
            loss 6 / 7
Epoch 001 | loss 2.1481332778930664 / 1.955793857574463
[...]
Epoch 100 | loss 1.9044179916381836 / 2.417532444000244
```

###### AUROC

I quickly computed the AUROC for each classes and each models, just to get an  idea of the order of magnitude of the overall performance of the models. Models 1 and 7 perform exactly the same (up to precision), they display the best AUROCs overall.

```
1 | [0.95196024 0.95413514 0.92944267 0.91018098 0.94650401 0.90678852 0.95304003 0.96580694 0.93578152 0.96045012]
2 | [0.87200175 0.87902421 0.80095353 0.79458389 0.81154274 0.753134340.85098344 0.89381936 0.79858213 0.84900242]
3 | [0.87200175 0.87902421 0.80095353 0.79458389 0.81154274 0.753134340.85098344 0.89381936 0.79858213 0.84900242]
4 | [0.87200175 0.87902421 0.80095353 0.79458389 0.81154274 0.753134340.85098344 0.89381936 0.79858213 0.84900242]
5 | [0.87200175 0.87902421 0.80095353 0.79458389 0.81154274 0.753134340.85098344 0.89381936 0.79858213 0.84900242]
6 | [0.86564374 0.87420285 0.79111195 0.75662811 0.79951567 0.749497540.85032598 0.88934953 0.79530107 0.84168291]
7 | [0.95196024 0.95413514 0.92944267 0.91018098 0.94650401 0.906788520.95304003 0.96580694 0.93578152 0.96045012]
```

###### Comparison of model states

I wanted to see how much each model's parameters would be different from the ones of the other models. I simply tested equality on all the weight/bias matrices and output whether *everything* is equal (up to an arbitrary precision, here 1e-10). Interestingly, the weight matrix of the input linear layer converged to the exact same for all the models, but not the bias matrix.

Also, models 1 and 7 have exactly the same weights, models 2, 3, 4 and 5 are also exactly the same, model 6 is the outlier.

```
1/2 (precision = 1e-10): {'Input (Linear)': (tensor(True), tensor(False)), 'Core (GRU)': (tensor(False), tensor(False), tensor(False), tensor(False)), 'Output (Linear)': (tensor(False), tensor(False))}
1/6 (precision = 1e-10): {'Input (Linear)': (tensor(True), tensor(False)), 'Core (GRU)': (tensor(False), tensor(False), tensor(False), tensor(False)), 'Output (Linear)': (tensor(False), tensor(False))}
1/7 (precision = 1e-10): {'Input (Linear)': (tensor(True), tensor(True)), 'Core (GRU)': (tensor(True), tensor(True), tensor(True), tensor(True)), 'Output (Linear)': (tensor(True), tensor(True))}
2/3 (precision = 1e-10): {'Input (Linear)': (tensor(True), tensor(True)), 'Core (GRU)': (tensor(True), tensor(True), tensor(True), tensor(True)), 'Output (Linear)': (tensor(True), tensor(True))}
2/4 (precision = 1e-10): {'Input (Linear)': (tensor(True), tensor(True)), 'Core (GRU)': (tensor(True), tensor(True), tensor(True), tensor(True)), 'Output (Linear)': (tensor(True), tensor(True))}
2/5 (precision = 1e-10): {'Input (Linear)': (tensor(True), tensor(True)), 'Core (GRU)': (tensor(True), tensor(True), tensor(True), tensor(True)), 'Output (Linear)': (tensor(True), tensor(True))}
2/6 (precision = 1e-10): {'Input (Linear)': (tensor(True), tensor(False)), 'Core (GRU)': (tensor(False), tensor(False), tensor(False), tensor(False)), 'Output (Linear)': (tensor(False), tensor(False))}
```